# Angular forms - reactive vs. [(ngModel)]

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, template, form, angular-2+

I am developing this angular app and it has big forms with 100 + fields. I was thinking about using `[(ngModel)]` without reactive forms, so that it's easier to do validations and I only have to provide the same JSON to the web service endpoint. Is this a right approach?

**Reactive forms**

```
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
  });
}

<input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
```

**Alternative**

```
    export class ProfileEditorComponent {
     profileForm = {
       firstName:""
     }
    }

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="profileForm.firstName">
```

My idea was to handle all the validations and everything manually.